# Issue with Kubernetes apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 with K8 Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-gcp, kubernetes-apiserver

We are using the networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 and we trying to move to networking.k8s.io/v1 with the following changes and my ingress.YAML code looks like this now.

Version:"v1.20.15-gke.2500"

When I applied the "kubectl apply" I got to see the following error, could someone help me why I am facing this error?

```
error: error validating "ingress.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.ServiceBackendPort: got "integer", expected "map", ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[1].backend.service.port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.ServiceBackendPort: got "integer", expected "map", ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[2].backend.service.port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.ServiceBackendPort: got "integer", expected "map"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ***
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ****
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: *****
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ***
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                 name: *********
                 port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                 name: *********
                 port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                 name: *********
                 port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                 name: *********
                 port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
    - host: *********
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                 service:
                   name: *********
                   port: 50000
          - path: /****/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
                service:
                  name: *********
                  port: 50000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Old format of YAML with API **networking.k8s.io/v1** it's updated now.

You can read more here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

Change in service port

```
            backend:
              service:
                name: test
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Ref YAML block :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: class-name
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax for `networking.k8s.io/v1` Ingress. The error is saying that the `backend.service.port` is no longer an integer, it expects a map.

In `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`, the `backend` section looks like below:

```yaml
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 80
```

Now in `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`:

```yaml
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

[Sample YAML](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```